# Uncaught TypeError: regexp.text is not a function

Tags: typeerror

This is my code:

```
function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {

  if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {

    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );

    updateTips( n );

    return false;

  } else {

    return true;

  }

}
```

It gives the following error:

[image]

Comment: Read your source code very carefully. You pasted here `regexp.test`, not text. Please fix the typo.

Comment: @ PatNowak - I update that, but showing same error again. can you please check http://pentafurniture.com/